# how to identify webp image type with python

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, webp

I want to identify the type of a Image to tell whether it's a `webp` format or not, but I can't just using `file` command because the image is stored in memory as binary which was download from the internet. so far I can't find any method to do this in the `PIL` lib or `imghdr` lib

here is what I wan't to do:

```
from PIL import Image
import imghdr

image_type = imghdr.what("test.webp")

if not image_type:
    print "err"
else:
    print image_type

# if the image is **webp** then I will convert it to 
# "jpeg", else I won't bother to do the converting job 
# because rerendering a image with JPG will cause information loss.

im = Image.open("test.webp").convert("RGB")
im.save("test.jpg","jpeg")
```

And when this `"test.webp"` is actually a `webp` image, `var image_type` is `None` which indict that the `imghdr` lib don't know a `webp` type, so is there any way that I can tell it's a `webp` image for sure with python?

---

For the record, I am using  python 2.7

---

Comment: yes, this conclusion was post in my question, I wan't to know is there any way to identify a `webp` image, with or without `imghdr` or `PIL` ?

Comment: do you have files with the .webp  extension that are not webp's?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes, in fact, the file was download directly from the internet so filename extention is not reliable, and `content-type` is not reliable either,  if that's what your means. The only way **for sure** to judge whether a file is a `webp` is according to its binary structure, the answer accepted gives a good way to solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `imghdr` module doesn't yet support webp image detection; it is to be [added to Python 3.5](http://bugs.python.org/issue20197).

Adding it in on older Python versions is easy enough:

```
import imghdr

try:
    imghdr.test_webp
except AttributeError:
    # add in webp test, see http://bugs.python.org/issue20197
    def test_webp(h, f):
        if h.startswith(b'RIFF') and h[8:12] == b'WEBP':
            return 'webp'

    imghdr.tests.append(test_webp)
```

Comment: @JashShah: `imghdr.test_webp` exists now, yes, as of Python 3.5.

Answer (score -1):

The imghdr will be Deprecated.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/imghdr.html

> Deprecated since version 3.11, will be removed in version 3.13: The imghdr module is deprecated (see PEP 594 for details and alternatives).

You can use `PIL`

```
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> img = Image.open('/tmp/imgc7e4913dbbde92e4256e89d702fc06af.jpg')
>>> img.format
'PNG'
>>> img = Image.open('/tmp/img29ba9e376d78288369b68702549d2b22.jpg')
>>> img.format
'WEBP'
```